# multiprocessing pool map each worker running code outside __main__ block

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

```py
import multiprocessing
import threading

counter = 1
print("Code outside __main__",counter)
lock = threading.Lock()
counter += 1

def foo(i):
  #print("Inside foo ",i)
  pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10)
  pool.map(foo, range(100))
```

if you run this code from the terminal `python run.py` it prints out

```
Code outside __main__ 1
Code outside __main__ 1
Code outside __main__ 1
Code outside __main__ 1
Code outside __main__ 1
Code outside __main__ 1
Code outside __main__ 1
Code outside __main__ 1
Code outside __main__ 1
```

and if you uncomment the print on foo() you see sometimes the `Code outside __main__ 1` is in between the foo() calls.

Why is it doing that?

---

```py
import multiprocessing
import threading

counter = 1
print("Code outside __main__",counter)
counter += 1

def foo(i):
  global lock
  with lock:
    print("Inside foo ",i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  lock = threading.Lock()
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10)
  pool.map(foo, range(100))
```

If I declare the lock inside the `__main__` block, it's undefined inside foo() even if I use `global lock`

Here's the output

```
Code outside __main__ 1
Code outside __main__ 1
Code outside __main__ 1
Code outside __main__ 1
Code outside __main__ 1
Code outside __main__ 1
Code outside __main__ 1
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Users\David\Documents\test.py", line 10, in foo
    with lock:
NameError: name 'lock' is not defined
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    pool.map(foo, range(100))
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
NameError: name 'lock' is not defined
Code outside __main__ 1
Code outside __main__ 1
```

This code is just a simplification, I'm trying to scrape a website and write to a file but I want to understand what's happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Part 1

> sometimes the Code `outside __main__ 1` is in between the foo() calls.

Each child process in the 10 you create with `multiprocessing.Pool` will `import *` from the "main" file, which basically means executing the file. You will get this print for the main process, and then 10 for the children. Particularly with more and more children, some of the early birds may get around to processing inputs from the `pool.map` call before others are done initializing, so this is why they can be interleaved. Also during this import, each process gets it's own version of the `counter` variable, so it will always be `1`.

### Part 2

> If I declare the lock inside the `__main__` block, it's undefined inside foo() even if I use `global lock`

`foo` is getting executed in a totally separate memory space. `global` can't automatically send objects to the memory of another process, and `lock` won't exist in theirs because they won't execute anything inside the `if` block (and they shouldn't). The children need to receive the lock as an argument and assign it to their own memory space. When using a `Pool` certain things like locks, queues, etc.. can only be passed as arguments to the initializer function (normal `Process`es don't have as many restrictions). You can then use the initializer to recieve the lock, and save it to the global space of the child's memory.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep
#mp.Lock is the same as threading.Lock, so save an import here

print("Code outside __main__")

def foo(i):
    global my_lock
    with my_lock:
        sleep(1)#counting 1 at a time means lock is working to limit access to a resource
        print("code inside foo ", i)
      
def init_worker(l):
    global my_lock
    my_lock = l

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = mp.Lock()
    with mp.Pool(processes=10, initializer=init_worker, initargs=(l,)) as pool:
        pool.map(foo, range(10))
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I thought with global you needed to have the variable declared beforehand outside the function and then you could modify it from inside, but I see that in `init_worker()` you first say that `my_lock` is global and THEN you declare it. Is that right? Does it work the same way?

Comment: you don't need it to be declared at the module level first, but you can if you'd like.. just assign some dummy value like `my_lock = None`. This can sometimes be useful in case you want a default value, but in this simplified case, there's really no point. I should also point out `global` is only "global" within the scope of a module (usually the scope of a single python file) imported libraries also don't have access to globals defined in your main file.

Comment: This exact case (passing things to the initializer of a `multiprocessing.Pool`) is one of the very few legitimate use cases of `global`, but should still be used sparingly. You can also pass locks directly as arguments when using the `Process` class rather than `Pool` (circumventing the need for globals), but pools do come with a lot of tools pre-built for you, and are nice for quick prototyping.